# ¿Cómo activo o desactivo un botón desde otro jframe en Java-Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, botón, jframe

Tengo 2 jframes "J1,J2", en el primer jframe tengo un botón desactivado por defecto "act" (solo le quite la palomita del Enabled en las propiedades del botón ) y un botón para ir al siguiente jframe "siguiente", hasta ahí todo bien, mi dificultad es que en el segundo jframe tengo un botón "pulsar" con el que quiero activar el botón que estaba desactivado en el primer jframe 
¿Como habilito ese botón desde mi segundo jframe?

Es para otro proyecto, solo que simplifique el problema para me puedan entender específicamente lo que necesito

[image]

Comment: El segundo JFrame lo invocas desde el primero ?. Si es asi podrias usar el patron Observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También lo puedes hacer en las mismas propiedades del botón que lo desactivaste en la pestaña Code-Variable Modifiers cambiándole de estado private a public y listo y desde el otro  botón llamas al formulario que desactivaste el botón y ahí mismo lo activas:

```
private void btnJ1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
  J2 form2=new J2();
  form2.btnJ2.setEnabled(true);
  form2.setVisible(true);
}
```

con esto ya lo activas al botón que esta des habilitado

Answer (score 0):

En la llamada al segundo frame que haces desde el botón siguiente, pasale el botón act y luego lo recuperas en el constructor del segundo frame

método actionlistener del primer frame:

```
sigBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Window2(actBtn);
        }
    });
```

constructor del segundo frame que yo llamé Window2:

```
public Window2(JButton btn1) {

    setTitle("Cuadro de texto");
    setBounds(COORDENADA_X, COORDENADA_Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    actBtn = new JButton("ACTIVAR");
    actBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btn1.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    panel.add(actBtn);
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);

}
```